# Why do I get "expected unqualified-id before »}«" from the compiler?

Tags: c++, boost, syntax, compilation

I copy-paste this code from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/poisson_dist.html):

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace math {

template <class RealType = double, 
          class Policy   = policies::policy<> >
class poisson_distribution;

typedef poisson_distribution<> poisson;

template <class RealType, class Policy>
class poisson_distribution
{ 
public:
  typedef RealType value_type;
  typedef Policy   policy_type;

  poisson_distribution(RealType mean = 1); // Constructor.
  RealType mean()const; // Accessor.
}

}} // namespaces boost::math
```

And get a compiler error:

```
expected unqualified-id before »}«
```

Comment: [`Totally a Poisson distribution!`](http://xkcd.com/12/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a semicolon on the outer close brace of your class definition. Could be  something else though, perhaps you could paste the full error and line numbers

```
...
 RealType mean()const; // Accessor.
}; <---
...
```

Comment: Thank you. You was right, it was the problem. I wonder why the official boost page contains example of the code with errors... Unfortunately, after the mentioned mistake was corrected I get other error messages.

Comment: @Roman I don't think it is supposed to be compilable code, but rather, to show the interface (including template parameters) of the `poisson_distribution` class template.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are new in C++. In C++ Class definition end with semicolon (`;`).